# Want to store rate while add/create new product

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, raty

I'm working on one application where I have to add rate a product while I'm adding(creating) it.
Right now I have used RatyRate but it is not storing the rates while I create/add product first time.

Is there any configuration to achieve this in RatyRate implementation?

If not then please suggest If there is any other gem to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create the rating component yourself which is quite simple. One simple way would be to add a `rating` `Model` which belongs to your `User` and a `rating` column to your `Product`.

However if you are looking for a gem, you can try [act_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and tweak it to your needs but it will be more difficult than building it yourself.